# How to append in Json String in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So this is my Json String

```
   {
      "method_name": "WSP.CC.GET.CARRIER.INFO",
      "calling_class": "com.fwdco.webservice.ScorpeoWebService",
      "error_code": "0",
      "contact_info": [
        [
          "name",
          "email",
          "phone"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

if i want to insert

```
           [
             "man"
             "man@yahoo.com"
             "534534646"
            ]
```

in contact_info, so that final json String is :

```
         {
  "method_name": "WSP.CC.GET.CARRIER.INFO",
  "calling_class": "com.fwdco.webservice.ScorpeoWebService",
  "error_code": "0",
  "contact_info": [
    [
      "name",
      "email",
      "phone"
    ],
    [
       "man"
       "man@yahoo.com"
       "534534646"
     ]
  ]
}
```

i tried to use splice and push function but it doesnt work.
Help plz

Comment: You should add the splice and push you tried... Perhaps you can simply push without a splice? contact_info.push(["man", "man@yahoo.com", "534534646"])

Comment: i tried data.contact_info.push(newcontact)  but it gives "contact_info": [
    [
      "name",
      "email",
      "phone"
    ],
    [ [
       "man"
       "man@yahoo.com"
       "534534646"
     ] ]
  ] I get this structure

Comment: Your array needs to be delimited: [ "man", "man@yahoo.com", "534534646" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/97mvba88/

```js
var obj = {
  "method_name": "WSP.CC.GET.CARRIER.INFO",
  "calling_class": "com.fwdco.webservice.ScorpeoWebService",
  "error_code": "0",
  "contact_info": [
    [
      "name",
      "email",
      "phone"
    ]
  ]

};


obj.contact_info.push(["man", "man@yahoo.com", '534534646']);
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.contact_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, here is a solution:

```
var myObject = {
    "method_name": "WSP.CC.GET.CARRIER.INFO",
    "calling_class": "com.fwdco.webservice.ScorpeoWebService",
    "error_code": "0",
    "contact_info": [
         [
           "name",
           "email",
           "phone"
         ]
    ]
};

myObject.contact_info.push([
  "man",
  "man@yahoo.com",
  "534534646"
]);
```